# iOS with custom GADRewardBasedVideoAd class crash

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I use Google Ads in my app. Because of my purpose, I created custom.

*GADRewardBasedVideoAd* class. So my code looks like this:

```
enum AdState {
    case rewarded
    case loaded
    case unknown
    case error
}

class VideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd {
    var adState: AdState = .unknown
}
```

And some ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let rewardAddNewsAd = VideoAd()

 ...

  rewardAddNewsAd.delegate = self
}
```

In the line of code where I set delegate app crash because of

> [App.VideoAd setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281c7fd20

If I change *rewardAddNewsAd* on class *GADRewardBasedVideoAd* and not my custom subclass everything works fine.

This code was working until Google updated GAD to the last version.

---

*I am using Swift 4.1*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a bug, but as described in [official site](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-video), `GADRewardBasedVideoAd` has a singleton design and you should not create your own subclasses. Use `GADRewardBasedVideoAd.shared` to access an instance of `GADRewardBasedVideoAd` class.

As an option, you can store the `AdState` somewhere outside `VideoAd`. For example, in `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

I used again not the singleton, but I did not use my subclass for GADRewardBasedVideoAd. For now, it was working. My point was I was getting different "coins" for each object.